# Get date from when app first opened

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, date, nsdate

I have an app that logs the amount of miles you travel, and it presents the data in a `UITableView`. A helpful thing I thought however, was to add since when this data was formed. Which would be the first time the app has opened right. So, how could I retrieve a date since the first time the app has opened. I thought of an approach that in the App Delegate, I get a `string` from a file. And if the string then is `nil`, it means the app has first been opened, then I add a simple `NSDate`. From there I copy a string into a file, so next time the app has opened the string will be valid and the app recognizes it has not been the first time the app has opened. Unfortunately this did not work.
Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults` for this purpose. On the launch check if `@"firstLaunchDate"` key is missing. If it is - this is the first launch of your app and you can store the launch date. Other times application will be launched - the condition will evaluate to false and won't overwrite previously set value.